# Erorr multiple databases on codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I am trying to build a project using multiple databases I use 3 databases in the project, sometimes the application runs normally but suddenly there is often a warning error about what database is wrong?

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/sbc-portal/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 436
```

Comment: All databases are mysql?

Comment: Yes every query error but later normal again but then error again

Comment: Set false persisten connection, increase mysql max connection limit

Comment: **I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This may caused to incorrect `Credentials`.**

Answer (score 2):

for secondary db add below code

```
$db['otherdb']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['otherdb']['username'] = "root";
$db['otherdb']['password'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['database'] = "other_database_name";
$db['otherdb']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['otherdb']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['otherdb']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['otherdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['otherdb']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['otherdb']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['otherdb']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['otherdb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['otherdb']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

then connect to secondary database

```
$otherdb = $this->load->database('otherdb', TRUE);
$test= $otherdb->get('test');
```

hope it works.